# Windows Phone 7 overflow clipping

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a grid within a grid and i want the content of the second to move about without encroaching on the first grid.

Much like the panorama view but can move left or right as well as up and down.

I can get this working but unfortunately when you move down the top overflows into the outer grid overlapping any controls within it.

Is there a way to hide the overflow almost like CSS overflow:hidden?

Any help would be really appropriated.

Thank you
Andrew

Possible solution:

```
var gridWidth = (this.tilesize * (this.gridSize - 1)) / 2;
var top = -(((-offsetY + tileY) * this.tilesize) - gridWidth);
var left = -(((-offsetX + tileX) * this.tilesize) - gridWidth);
this.Container.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
var clipSection = new RectangleGeometry();
clipSection.Rect = new Rect(-1 * left, -1 * top, 480, 400);
this.Container.Clip = clipSection;
this.Container.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
{
  this.Container.Clip = clipSection;
}));
```

Comment: I think i've found the solution.
You can use the Clip property to set the bounds.

var gridWidth = (this.tilesize * (this.gridSize - 1)) / 2;
var top = -(((-offsetY + tileY) * this.tilesize) - gridWidth);
var left = -(((-offsetX + tileX) * this.tilesize) - gridWidth);
this.Container.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
var clipSection = new RectangleGeometry();
clipSection.Rect = new Rect(-1 * left, -1 * top, 480, 400);
this.Container.Clip = clipSection;
this.Container.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
{
  this.Container.Clip = clipSection;
}));

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by putting something in the cells of the "outer" grid and seeing a higher ZIndex  than the elements you are moving around. The elements with the higher ZIndex appear above the lower ones.

Comment: That works OK but if i have a button underneath it then because the background is transparent it's hard to read. Likewise with TextBlocks too. I could set the background colour but would have to check the theme.